# How to map data to correspond to table headers by looping through 3 tables from db [C# MVC & LINQ]

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5

I have 3 tables namely: ImmunizationCategories, ImmunizationMaster and ImmunizationAdmins. See below
[image: ImmunizationCategories]

and 
[image: ImmunizationMaster]
and lastly
[image: ImmunizationAdmin]

ImmunizationCategories data goes to the BCG VACCINE: at birth. All the tables have been linked with FK_Constraint as can be seen. I am creating my report from ImmunizationAdmins to look like the report below:
[image: Report]

My challenge is mapping the data according to the column headers, for instance on BCG VACCINE column, below it (the empty cell), immunizationName belonging to BCG can be filled. Using LINQ, I have done this;

```
                    @foreach (var med in Model.immunizationAdmins.Where(e=>e.ImmunizationMasterId==e.ImmunizationMaster.Id && e.ImmunizationMaster.ImmunizationCategoryId == e.ImmunizationMaster.ImmunizationCategory.Id))
```

and also this

```
@foreach (var med in Model.immunizationAdmins.Where(e=>e.ImmunizationMasterId==e.ImmunizationMaster.Id && e.ImmunizationMaster.ImmunizationCategoryId == e.ImmunizationMaster.ImmunizationCategory.Id))

                    {
                        <td>@med.ImmunizationMaster.ImmunizationName)</td>


                    }
```

the query returns and fills the cells, though not according to the column header.This is how it looks like

[image: Result]

How do I map them?

Comment: Create the output table first adding all the columns.  Then group the data that goes in each row.  Finally add the group data to the table.  You are creating a Pivot Table.  See my answer at following posting : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45741333/how-to-convert-horizontal-data-into-vertical-from-database-to-datagridview-in-c/45741704#45741704

Comment: @jdweng, unfortunately the page of the link you shared cannot be found.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry.  The posting was closed.  I have enough points to read the link.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;


namespace ConsoleApplication73
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            dt.Columns.Add("R.N", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("Student Name", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Subjects", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Marks", typeof(int));

            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1, "Indra Poudel", "DBMS", 75 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1, "Indra Poudel", "SAD", 75 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1, "Indra Poudel", "TOC", 75 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 2, "John show", "DBMS", 75 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 2, "John show", "SAD", 75 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 2, "John show", "TOC", 75 });

            string[] subjects = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(x => x.Field<string>("Subjects")).Distinct().ToArray();

            DataTable pivot = new DataTable();
            pivot.Columns.Add("R.N", typeof(int));
            pivot.Columns.Add("Student Name", typeof(string));

            foreach (string subject in subjects)
            {
                pivot.Columns.Add(subject, typeof(int));
            }

            var groups = dt.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(x => x.Field<int>("R.N"));

            foreach (var group in groups)
            {
                DataRow newRow = pivot.Rows.Add();
                newRow["R.N"] = group.FirstOrDefault().Field<int>("R.N");
                newRow["Student Name"] = group.FirstOrDefault().Field<string>("Student Name");

                foreach (var col in group)
                {
                    newRow[col.Field<string>("Subjects")] = col.Field<int>("Marks");
                }

            }


        }
    }


}
```